# How can I make my skill listen/wait for a response for an indefinite amount of time

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

So I am trying to develop a skill that in short allows for users to ask for instructions on how to build various items step by step. However I am running into an issue when, for any given step, an intent will only listen for a response for a total of 16 seconds if a re-prompt is added.

This really hinders the skills because most things you build will have steps that take way longer than 16 seconds.

I am also solely developing this app to be run on devices that support APL so I'm not sure if that information could be of help.

Ive tried using a hacky way of using ssml to play a silent audio file but it can only play files that are at max 90 seconds long, which still isn't enough time. So if any one can lead me in the right direction to solving this issue that would be much appreciated.

Comment: the limit for a <audio src=  /> ssml tag is now 240 seconds and there is a limit to 5 audio tag responses per response still that's 20 minutes of dead air time you could add per response, probably very bad UI. why don't you ask the user after a decent break if they are ready to continue, or need more time this creates more back and forth response and is a better choice. It's Amazons platform you'll have to develop by their parameters, They don't want open mic's on the devices.

Comment: References for time limits I quoted are here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio  and the stringing together of audio tags was addressed in this S/O question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53881804/amazon-s3-tags-when-put-together-if-more-then-five-then-the-combination-doesnt/53932986#53932986

Comment: @ChuckLaPress Thanks for the response I'll probably end up throwing 5 of those in there, It would be nice to have unlimited time for steps due to the fact that this is going to be used in engineering and manufacturing processes. It would be quite annoying to be asked if you want to continue with the next step every 5 minutes while you are cranking some metal out on a lathe or soldering some complicated circuit.

Comment: Have you thought about persisting the sessions via a data layer? So a complex 5 step process allows a user to relaunch when ready, between step two and step three. When the relaunch your skill says welcome back we were completing step two are you ready for the next step.  This will provide much better UX and honestly Amazon probably won’t certify a skill that waits long periods with the mics open.

Comment: @ChuckLaPress yeah we have thought about it and decided to go with a closed session approach where we use persistent session attributes, you'd just have to use your Alexa wake word along side our invocation name for every action you take. I don't know if you have ever used allRecipes skill but we are tying to model it similar to there closed session approach.